# Reliable fail-safe optoisolator

Tags: opto-isolator, mains, pulse, reliability

I would like to add an extra fail-safe to a optocoupler. My current approach is to transmit a pulse of very specific frequency and pulsewidth on a clock on the high voltage side through the optocoupler and have a circuit on the low voltage side of my circuit that is synchronised with the clock on the high voltage side. Then it would be able to detect these sync pulses on the output of the optocouplerand only respond to my microcontroller via I²C if it received the last synchronisation pulse. If it does not receive a sync pulse at the given time i can conclude that the optocoupler is broken and react accordingly. how would i design a circuit in such a way that it detects if no sync pulse is transmitted over the optocoupler for one sync cycle and thus trigger a contactor to isolate the power systems from mains?

Comment: before the design comes a usable specification of how it is supposed to behave. You might look up the term 'watchdog'.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to detect if an optocoupler is broken by using it in a way that has no other purpose. Isn't that not really useful?

Comment: What's the signal that has to pass through the opto? You could send two types of 'message', one being 'I am alive and the signal is not present', the other being 'I am alive and the signal is present'.

Comment: Neil_UK: i just need to pass a single bit of data through the opto. so this would definitely work.how would these messages differ? in pulsewidth perhaps?

Comment: You can XOR your data to send and these short sync pulses. So you receive either short high or short low pulses and everythings else is bad.

Comment: perfect! Thank you so very much to everyone who took part in very helpfully answering this question! Also: Jens: this is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you so much!